# Помогите с Decrypt

Tags: php, c#

Подскажите как на php decrypt-овать текст, собранный в C# с отправленный post запросом на сайт.Текст crypt-ую кодом

```
private static byte[] HexToBytes(string hex) {
    if (hex != null) {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        if (hex.Length > 1 && hex.Length % 2 == 0) {
            byte[] result = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
                result[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    return new byte[0];
}

private static string Encrypt(string text) {
    Byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    for (int i = buffer.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer[i] ^= buffer[i + 1];
    }
    buffer[buffer.Length - 1] ^= buffer[0];
    return BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: Почему бы готовое что-нибудь не использовать, зачем выдумывать свой алгоритм странный? Тот же `System.Security.Cryptography.DES`.

Comment: @Suvitruf потому,что готовое сразу разберут и получать текст

Comment: https://habr.com/post/181372/